# Insert MT4/MT5 custom indicator to tradingview?

Tags: c++, pine-script, metatrader4, metatrader5

I need to know if I can transfer my custom indicator from MetaTrader 4/5 to tradingview?
If it is possible by simply transferring it across great! If not I need to know what I have to do.

Any help will be great,
Thank you!

Comment: I don’t believe a direct transfer is possible. However, you can probably code it yourself in pine-script.

Comment: If anyone can code the transfer I am willing to pay for the job done.

Comment: You need to tell us more about your indicator to see if that is possible at all.

Comment: Hi Baris, the indicator is coded with C++, I have MQL4 / MQL5 versions and need to know if it will be easy to transfer to tradingview, the code is not that long "389".